# Repeated State changes in Opengl

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, gpu

```
   Its a fact that state changes in Opengl leads to performance degradation.
```

//Say If i'm calling glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) / glBlendFunc repeatedly in every frame.

EDIT:  >Here I just mean to say 'some state changes like this which state changes cause performance problems'

Can any one please explain the reason for this in detailed?

> To my knowledge, The states can be maintained with in a register and can be used in traditional rendering GPU(Immediate mode kind) or can maintain a state
>   vector for each draw call in  Tile based deferred Rendering. Is this really costly to maintain? (wonder why GPU's are having still this problem :( )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Indeed state changes may be a performance killer. However the important question to ask is: "Which state". Some state changes are so cheap, that is simply doesn't make sense to keep track of them to minimize their use.

On today's OpenGL implementations `glEnable`/`glDisable` have virtually no performance penality (of course some states en-/disabled have large influence on the rendering performance in general).

So what are expensive state changes? About everything that kills the caches' contents, and the data in the cache is to be accessed at high bandwidth or requires high throughput.

Textures are about the most expensive source of data to switch. So as a basic rule you sort your scene by use of textures, to switch textures as few as possible.

Another expensive state change is switching shaders. Switching a shader affects the GPU in a negatively in two ways: First it forces the processing units into a full stop, flushing their execution pipeline. Refilling the pipeline until the thing works "like clockwork" takes a few hundred cycles. The other problem is, that different shaders have different execution and data access patterns. Execution patterns are determined by codepath prediction units to estimate which operations are about to be executed most likely. This also means knowing, which data to prefetch. Switching the shader trashes this vital information.

States that are very cheap, but not for free is anything that can be described by a small set of numbers: Uniforms. Switching uniforms is extremely cheap, since it requires only very little overhead in the communication with the GPU and since Uniforms live in registers, changing them will effect neither cachelines nor execution prediction. And if you're wondering about traditional, fixed function OpenGL: Transformation matrices, lighting parameters, clip planes are uniforms (just look into the OpenGL-2.1 GLSL spec, which built-in uniforms there are).

Comment: Thts Really informative! Thanks datenwolf! one small clarification...When considering Tile Based Deferred Rendering (Power VR GPU Cards),Sorting based on position(for faster tiler fetch) of objects is better or sorting on texture indices would be better?

Comment: @Ayyappa: I can't say for sure, but the nature of TBDR, optimized for low memory bandwidth requirements suggests this. However sorting by position requires significant processing on the CPU and for what I know PowerVR does this with the geometry in the drivers, on the CPU anyway. So if I had to make an educated guess I'd say, sorting by the usual scheme is still the best, though PowerVRs may profit by sort by shader. Franky, I'd to benchmark it, to make a qualified statement.

Comment: thanks for the info! i will also try to benchmark it in free time...but pls share the results if you do so...

Comment: @Ayyappa: For that I need a own device with PowerVR GPU first. So far I'm only developing on simulators and test on friends' or colleagues' devices -- believe it or not: I neither own a modern smartphone, nor a tablet; I'm totally behind the trends, regarding that. My smartphone is totally outdated, and that tablet thingy I have is an anachronism.

Comment: @datenwolf: Does that mean that changing shaders is less expensive than switching textures?

Comment: @Dudeson: It strongly depends on the GPU generation. The only way to make a definitive statement is to profile it. However in my experience switching shaders takes less cost than switching textures (except with older NVidia drivers which were prone to recompile shaders based on uniform state).

Comment: @datenwolf: Wow! That really surprises me! In my engine I was always sorting by shader, then by mesh (because multiple instances of the same mesh use the same textures) and then by texture... Do you think it would be worth it to change that order?

Comment: Since you will use the same shader for a lot of geometry and textures, and since you'll use a completely different set of textures for different shaders, the practical approach will be that you sort by textures first, by shaders second. Due to the the association between textures and shaders that also minimizes shader switches. –– BTW for a long time the recommendation was to first sort geometry close to far to make efficient use of early depth testing. This is still done in multipass renderers, which use occlusion query to tune their rendering queue and in deferred renderers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` would not incur significant performance degradation.

The expensive state changes I believe are shader program binds, buffer binds, texture binds and buffer offset/stride changes. Because these require validation to ensure that the buffer is large enough etc.

If you think this could be affecting performance you can order elements to be rendered by material (textures, shaders, depth testing) before rendering, and perform the state changes only once.

Comment: ok then can you please explain WHY texture bind can be an issue?

Comment: Either it is causing some expensive validation, is it a valid texture?
If there is a cache between video ram (or main memory whichever the iphone has) it could cause a fetch of the texture data into the cache.
I can only find a single forum post that supports what I think is expensive but doesn't explain why it's expensive. http://www.gamedev.net/topic/416620-opengl-state-change-benchmark-data/

Answer (score 0):

You should enable some opengl state only if you disabled it first. So there is no reason to call `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` or `glBlendFunc` every frame if you don't need such changes

Comment: forget about the example taken , can you please help me in explaining the reason for that please....  To contradic your answer , its a general practice to set client enable states for vertices/colors  arrays - ofcourse which is not recommended.But i just want to know why its causing performance problem.

Comment: @Ayyappa: actually i totally agree with eyesathousand, that enabling/disabling depth test is not affecting performance much. Answering your question: opengl is a state machine. So once you setup a state it will be kept until changed